# Access attrs in AngularJS directive templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a problem as I don't understand AngularJS directives 100% yet. I have a directive like so,

in my HTML:

```
<div my-directive="Hello World"></div>
```

in my Directive JS file:

```
.directive('myDirective', [function ( ) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 100,
            templateUrl: 'views/templates/my-directive.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                // I wish to pass attrs.myDirective to the templateUrl
            }
        };
    }]);
```

and in my templateUrl 'views/templates/my-directive.html':

```
<h1> {{ attrs.myDirective }} </h1>
```

Obviously this does work, my directive value is passed to the link function but not to the templateUrl, how can I output the value in my templateUrl? Silly question I know but I'm not sure what the best way to implement this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assigned this value to scope variable.

```
  scope.myDirective=attrs.myDirective

app.directive('myDirective', [function ( ) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 100,
            templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              scope.myDirective=attrs.myDirective
                // I wish to pass attrs.myDirective to the templateUrl
            }
        };
    }]);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kCO2XdEMmFjF9ZuHXsu4)

Comment: I originally did this and it worked, however I was unsure if I was to use the compile feature to pass the attr this to the templateUrl

Comment: there is no need of compile here untill you will have dynamic tempalte :)